# How to know the name of the object in tkinter

Tags: python, select, tkinter

I need just to know how to get the name of one of my two textbox when I press a key.

I've two textbox, one named 'Text1' and the second,  'Text2'. I want when I put my cursor on the first one, I press a key (like p) and it print 'you have your cursor on the Text1!' And same when I place my cursor on the second textbox. 
It is possible?

Comment: it is very possible with bindings.

Comment: Do you _really_ need the name, or do you only _think_ you need the name? And by "name" do you mean the name of the variable? What purpose does knowing the name serve? What is the real problem you are trying  to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can us bindings to get the kind of behavior you are looking for.

we need to use frames to hold each text widget and then bind the `<Enter>` even to each frame that then sends a command to a method to set the focus on the frame the mouse is currently in.

We also bind the letter `p` to each frame that will use a lambda print statement to print out the name of the text box that is inside of that frame.

Here is a simple example, You can mouse over each text box and without clicking with the mouse if you press `p` you will see in the console the name of the text box.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def set_focus(x):
    x.focus_force()

text1_frame = tk.Frame(root)
text1_frame.pack()
text1_frame.bind("p", lambda x: print("text1"))
text1_frame.bind("<Enter>", lambda x: set_focus(text1_frame))

text2_frame = tk.Frame(root)
text2_frame.pack()
text2_frame.bind("p", lambda x: print("text2"))
text2_frame.bind("<Enter>", lambda x: set_focus(text2_frame))

text1 = tk.Text(text1_frame, height = 4, width = 10)
text1.pack()

text2 = tk.Text(text2_frame, height = 4, width = 10)
text2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

A slightly different way that does not manipulate the focus would be to just update a variable with the current location of the mouse and to bind `p` to root and to call a print function.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
m_location = "root"

def mouse_location(x):
    global m_location
    m_location = x

text1_frame = tk.Frame(root)
text1_frame.pack()
text1_frame.bind("<Enter>", lambda x: mouse_location("text1"))
text1_frame.bind("<Leave>", lambda x: mouse_location("root"))

text2_frame = tk.Frame(root)
text2_frame.pack()
text2_frame.bind("<Enter>", lambda x: mouse_location("text2"))
text2_frame.bind("<Leave>", lambda x: mouse_location("root"))

text1 = tk.Text(text1_frame, height = 4, width = 10)
text1.pack()

text2 = tk.Text(text2_frame, height = 4, width = 10)
text2.pack()

def print_if(event = None):
    global m_location
    print(m_location)

root.bind("p", print_if)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help and sorry I'm late. This answer is just very good and it help me. I find by after the way to print widget name but your way is better! Thanks

Comment: After some searches I find the binding <FocusIn> which is better for me but thanks for your help with bindings